# Is there a DRY way to "git submodule add git@url" with ansible?

Tags: ansible, git-submodules

Straight forward question. MY playbook creates a new project on gitlab and then It clones it on all the host. Now I want for one host to enter the project and create a .gitmodules files with "git submodule add git@some-url.git" only once.

the git module for ansible only has track_submodules parameter but that updates the submodule which will be useful later. And I wouldn't like using the shell module in this case.

Essentially I just want an automatic ansible way to create a new project with a specific submodule.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first check if the submodule exists. You can just use the `stat` module to verify that the directory exists, and then only run your `git submodule add ...` command if the submodule directory doesn't exist. Something like:

```
- name: check if submodule exists
  stat:
    path: mysubmodule
  register: mysubmodule_check

- name: add submodule
  command: git submodule add {{ submodule_url }} mysubmodule
  when: not mysubmodule_check.stat.exists
```

Comment: What if I want to add more than one submodule in .gitmodules file?